# When using Zen and Zen grids, where do I put SASS variables?

Tags: theming

I am trying to use Zen Grids with the Zen ver. 5 starter theme.

The Zen starter theme comes with a lot of `.scss` files (in the `sass/` subdirectory).  I am trying to use Zen Grids to set up a simple layout.  I've read up on Sass and think I understand the concept, and I've Compass installed and working.

I've read everything on the [Zen Grids](http://zengrids.com/) website. On the front page of that website, below the promising headline: "Using Zen Grids is easy!", there is a nice introduction to Sass and Zen Grids followed by: "And here’s the complete Sass code:".

The example is strightforward enough.  What I am not able to figure out is *where* (as in "in what file") you put the statements used in the example.

(My setup is a Zen sub-theme created from the Zen `STARTERKIT`, straight out of the box.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the Zen `STARTERKIT` ver. 5, *Sass* configuration variables and *Sass* mix-ins similar to those you link to on the [**Zen Grids**](http://zengrids.com/) website is *already* in place in the file named `responsive-sidebars.scss`.

So to create a responsive design by means of **Zen Grids**, you don't add these anywhere, as they're already in place. But if you want to *change* them to other values, you do so by simply editing `responsive-sidebars.scss` in your starterkit sub-theme.

Note that most of the selectors used in the example on the **Zen Grids** website (e.g. `.aside1`) will not do anything in Zen (unless you also change the corresponding template file).  You can see from `responsive-sidebars.scss` what selectors to use (e.g. `.region-sidebar-first`).

Answer (score 3):

In the Zen theme structure there are several main style files: pages.scss, nodes.scss, blocks.scss, forms.scss. Depend on which part of website that you want to make styles. You have to choose the correct files for changing. In order to use the sample code in the [Zen Grids](http://zengrids.com/) . You can go to pages.scss and make changes here . Make sure that your website will generate the same HTML markup structure like the sample by creating new pages.tpl.php.